# How can you upgrade Go version to 1.2.1 on Nitrous.io?

Tags: go, nitrousio

How can you upgrade Go version to 1.2.1 on Nitrous.io? Default version on a Go box is 1.1.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update it via the package manager, Autoparts: http://help.nitrous.io/autoparts/

I believe Go 1.2.1 is available in the repository: https://github.com/nitrous-io/autoparts/blob/master/lib/autoparts/packages/go.rb#L8

The command is:

```
parts install go
```